# SQL Server не видит индекс

Tags: sql-server

В общем, на колонке есть индекс.

Строю план запросов, а он мне говорит, что необходимо создать индекс на колонке, где этот индекс уже имеется и точно такой же.

Если прибить индекс руками через хинты, то сообщение пропадает, НО при этом запрос начинает тупить.

Почему так может происходить? Пробовал даже ребилд делать, но ничего не поменялось.

Собственно, вот подробности, правда, я заанонимировал запрос:

```
DECLARE @Variable1 INT= ?;
SELECT Object2.Column1,
       Object2.Column2,
       Object2.Column3,
       Column4 = CASE
                     WHEN EXISTS
(
    SELECT ?
    FROM Object3(nolock)
    WHERE Column2 = Object2.Column2
          AND Column5 NOT LIKE ?
)
                     THEN
(
    SELECT Column6
    FROM Object4 WITH (nolock)
         JOIN Object3 Object5(nolock) ON Object5.Column2 = Object4.Column2
    WHERE Object4.Column2 = Object2.Column2+?
          AND Column5 LIKE ?
          AND MultiPartIdentifier1.Function1(Object2.Column6) = MultiPartIdentifier1.Function1(Object4.Column6)
)
                     ELSE ?
                 END,
       Object2.Column6 AS Column7,
       Object2.Column8,
       Object2.Column9,
       Object2.Column10
FROM Object4 Object2 WITH (nolock)
WHERE Column2 IN
(
    SELECT Column2
    FROM Object3(nolock)
    WHERE Column11 = Variable1
          AND Column5 NOT LIKE ?
);
```

Общий смысл запрос- это присоединить к текущей записи запись из этой де таблицы, но с PK+1 с дополнительным условием в виде скалярной функции, которая обрезает название файла в пути к Файлу и подтянуть эти данные в отдельную колонку текущей записи.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Предлагают сделать вот такой индекс:

```
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>]
ON [Schema1].[Object4] ([Column2])
GO
```

Вот такой индекс висит уже на колонке:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Name] ON [dbo].[TableName]
(
    [Field] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Sql Server 2008 R2

В таблицах ~1 000 000 записей, но в результате запроса возвращается не более 
1 000

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79771/discussion-on-question-by-iluxa1810-sql-server---).

Comment: По коду в вопросе вообще непонятно, что происходит, на скрине пачка индексов, в коде - один и какой-то левый.